# beaglebone black /dev/ttyACM1 issues

Tags: serial-port, usb, beagleboneblack

I have an issue with /dev/ACM1 of BB black. I am trying to read data from a radar sensor (IWR1443BOOST Texas Instrument) via USB connection to BeagleBone Black.  If I use my PC and connect it directly to the radar via USB, select the right COM port on putty and the right baud rate,  I can receive all the binaries I need without having to install any driver.  When I connect the radar  to BeagleBone, the sensor  should show itself as ttyACM1.  However, this port  ttyACM1 is not always visible in /dev and exhbits random behaviour: sometimes it shows up, sometimes it does not. Sometimes it shows up as ACM2 isntead of ACM1. Furthermore when I try to read data tha I receive from this port (e.g. thorugh cat command), I am not able to read all the data that the radar is streaming and sometimes the cat command exits becuase there is not ttyACM1 anymore.  It is important to mention that I set the baud rate of ACM1 with stty -F /dev/ttyACM1 921600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb.   I tried with different BeagleBones but the problem persists. Are there issues with ACM ports? THe sensor should  not require any driver.

Comment: This community is about programming-related questions.

Comment: It looks like a hardware issue. Make sure your BBB is powered well (reliable power source) and that the USB connections are good (including the solderings on the board) . I would have also tried to use `minicom` to read data instead of `stty`.